# Ember stopping propogation of action handlers

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a layout where an action handlers is given to the parent div and another action handler is given to the child li elements.

Now when the li element is clicked the action handler triggers and again the bubbling triggers the action handler of its parent.

I need to stop the bubbling of the action handlers by li element and need to arrest the further bubbling.

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div {{action 'headerAction'}} style="border:1px solid red;">
    Parent Div 

    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
        <li {{action 'liAction'}}>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

app.js

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
},
actions:{
headerAction: function(){
  alert('headerAction');
},
liAction: function(e){
  alert('liAction');
}
}
});
```

JSBIN [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xakivo/1/)

Comment: Did you try `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();` on the event as the first two lines inside the action method?

Comment: I could not get the event inside actions handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside of a template, you can pass the `bubbles=false` option to prevent that behavior.

```
<li {{action 'liAction' bubbles=false}}></li>
```

Also, this is something that isn't necessary, but when adding the `bubbles` option, I also find it helpful to explicitly declare the event type:

```
<li {{action 'liAction' on='click' bubbles=false}}></li>
```

You can read more about event bubbling (and other action options) in the guide [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_stopping-event-propagation).

Comment: Isn't this confusing bubbling Ember action up the route chain with propagating DOM events to ancestors?

Comment: No, they're different ideas (although the same name). Adding `bubbles=false` to the `action` helper will not prevent Ember actions from bubbling up the route hierarchy, that happens by default. You can change that behavior by explicitly returning `true` from your Ember action handler. The `bubbles` parameter in the `action` helper only deals with DOM events (as you can see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.11.1/packages/ember-routing-htmlbars/lib/helpers/action.js#L81)).